# How to get second level pages on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a Page structure that looks like this:

```
Home
  Page1
    Page1a
    Page1b
      Page1b-a
  Page2
  Page3
    Page3a
```

Is there any way to get only the second level pages (Page1 , Page2 and Page3)??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm still on the first level. The end boss is hard. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Home an actual Page? If so you query where `post_parent = id of Home`. Are you writing a query directly against the database or using wp_list_pages?

wp_list_pages has a child_of parameter:

```
wp_list_pages('child_of=#');
```

EDIT: Can use get_pages to pull back an array of pages, pretty much same parameters as wp_list_pages:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: Home is a page, but I need an object of the pages, so I cant use wp_list_pages